# ¿Para qué sirve exactamente el modificador ^~ de Nginx?

Tags: nginx

Necesito saber con claridad y algún ejemplo para qué sirve exactamente el modificador **^~** de nginx, ya que por mucho que intento leer en los tutoriales que encuentro, no termino por aclararme y ver la diferencia exacta entre el resto de modificadores.

Este parece ser uno de los que más claro los explica, pero aún así sigo sin entenderlo claramente: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

> ^~: If a carat and tilde modifier is present, and if this block is selected as the best non-regular expression match, regular expression matching will not take place.

Por ejemplo, como en este ejemplo: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms?comment=68515 ¿en qué se diferencia?:

```
location  ~ /1/2/3/4/ { add_header X-message "5" always; }       
location ^~ /1/2/3/4/ { add_header X-message "2" always; }
```

Ref2: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: eso se conoce como [wildcard](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

Comment: También está tomado de las expresiones regulares, siempre es bueno estudiarlas y conocer un poco más

Answer (score 0):

Este está presente para garantizar que la URL completa coincida al realizar la reescritura.

Por ejemplo, sin el ^, estas URL coincidirían:

```
   > location  ~ /1/2/3/4/ { add_header X-message "5" always; }       
    > location ^~ /1/2/3/4/ { add_header X-message "2" always; }
```

y eso no se debe. 
Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Hola Erica bienvenida a stackoverflow , te invito a hacer el [tour] , ten en cuenta agregar documentacion oficial para que tu respuesta se buena

Comment: A que usted se refiere con documentacion oficial? yo puse mis brackts en el exmaple code.